# Trying to succes transaction in Tron network to snd usdt using c# and TronNet Nudget package

Tags: c#, blockchain, tron

I have used TronNet nudget packages version 0.2.0
but there is always some bug. So I collected the method based on documentation and some other examples.

I have been trying to get simply transfer usdt assets using tron network, it seems packages not working well.Here one of the many transfer trial

```
public static async Task TransferTrc20Token(string tokenContractAddress, string walletAddress,
    string privateKey, string toAddress, decimal amount)
        {
            // Create the transfer contract
            var transferContract = new TransferContract
            {
                OwnerAddress = ByteString.CopyFrom(Base58Encoder.DecodeFromBase58Check(walletAddress)),
                ToAddress = ByteString.CopyFrom(Base58Encoder.DecodeFromBase58Check(toAddress)),
                Amount = (long)(amount * 1000000m)
            };

            // Create the transaction
            var transaction = new Transaction
            {
                RawData = new Transaction.Types.raw
                {
                    Contract = { new Transaction.Types.Contract
                    {
                        Type = Transaction.Types.Contract.Types.ContractType.TransferContract,
                        Parameter = Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Any.Pack(transferContract)
                    }},
                    Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds(),
                    Expiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(1).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
                }
            };

            // Sign the transaction
            transaction = SignTransaction(transaction, privateKey);

            // Serialize the transaction
            var serializedTransaction = transaction.ToByteArray();

            // Convert the serialized transaction to hexadecimal string
            var transactionHex = BitConverter.ToString(serializedTransaction).Replace("-", "");

            // Create the REST client
            var client = new RestClient("https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/easytransfer");
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.Method = Method.Post;
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"transaction\":\"" + transactionHex + "\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

            // Send the request
            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                // Handle successful response
                Console.WriteLine("Transfer successful");
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle error response
                Console.WriteLine("Transfer failed: " + response.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        private static Transaction SignTransaction(Transaction transaction, string privateKey)
        {
            byte[] privateKeyBytes;
            if (privateKey.Length == 64)
            {
                privateKeyBytes = StringToByteArray(privateKey);
            }
            else
            {
                // Decode private key from Base58Check format
                privateKeyBytes = TronNet.Crypto.Base58Encoder.DecodeFromBase58Check(privateKey);
            }

            var ecKey = new ECKey(privateKeyBytes, true);
            var rawdata = transaction.RawData.ToByteArray();
            var hash = rawdata.ToSHA256Hash();
            var signature = ecKey.Sign(hash).ToByteArray();

            transaction.Signature.Add(ByteString.CopyFrom(signature));

            return transaction;
        }

        private static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
        {
            int length = hex.Length;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2)
            {
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
            }
            return bytes;
        }
```

To find what is problem? and process transaction in tron network usdt c#,

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a couple of problems actually;

- The code is missing two required attributes in the RawData section, which you can get by fetching the latest block, [reference @ v4.7.2](https://developers.tron.network/docs/tron-protocol-transaction)

  - `ref_block_bytes` using the height of the block as BigEndianlong bytes, the 6th to 8th (exclusive).
  - `ref_block_hash` using the 8th to 16th (exclusive) bytes of the reference block hash.
- Also I'm not sure which version of Full Node HTTP API of Tron you are using but `/wallet/easytransfer` endpoint was deprecated with v4.7.1, and I think you are trying to send a signed transaction hex which would use the endpoint `wallet/broadcasthex`. [reference @ v4.7.2](https://developers.tron.network/reference/broadcasthex)

Answer (score 0):

**TronWallet SDK**

You can run the following command to install the Tron in your project.

```
PM> Install-Package TronWallet
```

**Configuration**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace ConsoleApp1;

using Tron;

public record TronRecord(IServiceProvider ServiceProvider, ITronClient? TronClient, IOptions<TronNetOptions>? Options);

public static class TronServiceExtension {
    private static IServiceProvider AddTron() {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddTronNet(x => {
            x.Network = TronNetwork.MainNet;
            x.Channel = new GrpcChannelOption { Host = "grpc.trongrid.io", Port = 50051 };
            x.SolidityChannel = new GrpcChannelOption { Host = "grpc.trongrid.io", Port = 50052 };
            x.ApiKey = "80a8b20f-a917-43a9-a2f1-809fe6eec0d6";
        });
        services.AddLogging();
        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public static TronRecord GetRecord() {
        var provider = AddTron();
        var client = provider.GetService<ITronClient>();
        var options = provider.GetService<IOptions<TronNetOptions>>();

        return new TronRecord(provider, client, options);
    }
}
```

**Sample 1: Generate Address Offline**

```
namespace ConsoleApp1;

using Tron;

internal class Program {    
    private static void Main() {
        var tronEcKey = TronECKey.GenerateKey(TronNetwork.MainNet);
        var privateKey = tronEcKey.GetPrivateKey();
        var address = tronEcKey.GetPublicAddress();

        Console.WriteLine($"{privateKey}\t{address}");
    }
}
```

**Sample 2: Transfer TRX/USDT and account permission update**

```
namespace ConsoleApp1;

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using Tron;
using Tron.Accounts;
using Tron.Contracts;

internal class Program {
    private static async Task Main() {
        var privateKey = "your private key here.";
        var toAddress = "your receive address here.";
        var amount = 1_000_000L;

        //transfer out trx
        var result = await TrxTransferAsync(privateKey, toAddress, amount);
        Console.WriteLine(result.TransactionId);

        //transfer out usdt
        var decimalAmount = new decimal(1);
        var transactionId = await EtherTransferAsync(privateKey, toAddress, decimalAmount, null);
        Console.WriteLine(transactionId);

        //Account permission update
        var ownerAddress = "your owner address here.";
        var r = await AccountPermissionUpdateAsync(privateKey, ownerAddress);
        Console.WriteLine(r.TransactionId);
    }


    private static async Task<dynamic> TrxTransferAsync(string privateKey, string to, long amount) {
        var record = TronServiceExtension.GetRecord();
        var transactionClient = record.TronClient?.GetTransaction();

        var account = new TronAccount(privateKey, TronNetwork.MainNet);

        var transactionExtension = await transactionClient?.CreateTransactionAsync(account.Address, to, amount)!;

        var transactionId = transactionExtension.Txid.ToStringUtf8();

        var transactionSigned = transactionClient.GetTransactionSign(transactionExtension.Transaction, privateKey);
        var returnObj = await transactionClient.BroadcastTransactionAsync(transactionSigned);

        return new { Result = returnObj.Result, Message = returnObj.Message?.ToStringUtf8(), TransactionId = transactionId };
    }

    private static async Task<string> EtherTransferAsync(string privateKey, string toAddress, decimal amount, string? memo) {
        const string contractAddress = "TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t";

        var record = TronServiceExtension.GetRecord();
        var contractClientFactory = record.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContractClientFactory>();
        var contractClient = contractClientFactory?.CreateClient(ContractProtocol.TRC20);

        var account = new TronAccount(privateKey, TronNetwork.MainNet);

        const long feeAmount = 60 * 1000000L;

        return await contractClient.TransferAsync(contractAddress, account, toAddress, amount, memo, feeAmount);
    }

    private static async Task<dynamic> AccountPermissionUpdateAsync(string privateKey, string ownerAddress) {
        var record = TronServiceExtension.GetRecord();
        var transactionClient = record.TronClient?.GetTransaction();
        var account = new TronAccount(privateKey, TronNetwork.MainNet);

        var transactionExtention = await transactionClient?.CreateAccountPermissionUpdateTransactionAsync(account.Address, ownerAddress)!;

        var transactionSigned = transactionClient.GetTransactionSign(transactionExtention.Transaction, privateKey);
        var returnObj = await transactionClient.BroadcastTransactionAsync(transactionSigned);

        return new { Result = returnObj.Result, Message = returnObj.Message?.ToStringUtf8(), TransactionId = transactionExtention.Transaction.GetTxid() };
    }
}
```